# Go to next problem (f8) - How to remove message

Tags: remap, vscode-keybinding, vs-code-settings

I use "Error lens" extension, so I can see the msg of the problem on my code, and I want to be able to press f8 and go to the next problem without showing the msg. Vscode just offers 4 commands for error, no way for "disable error msg"

You can exit that msg with Escape, I was trying different remaps but nothing works:

```json
{
      "command": "runCommands",
      "key": "shift+alt+6",
      "args": {
         "commands": [
            "editor.action.marker.nextInFiles",
            "workbench.action.closeQuickOpen",
         ]
      }
   },
```

I think that I want the same behavior that you get with: `workbench.actions.view.problems` but without opening the terminal